# Observable from array of length 1 returning object

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable

I have a function that returns an Observable. It looks like this:

```
public dissasemble (file) {
    const signatureContainers = [someOtherFunc(file)];
    return from(signatureContainers);
}
```

It is called from another function like this:

```
public verify (file) {
    dissasemble(file).subscribe(signatureContainers  => {
        signatureContainers.forEach(sc => { // I get an exception here because signatureContainers is an object and not an array
            // do something
        });
    });
}
```

When I debug the code exection inside subscribe I see that signatureContainer is an object instead of array

Comment: I guess you are looking for Observable `of` here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) about the `from` function, you can see that it says the following:

> For arrays and iterables, all contained values will be emitted as a sequence!

This means that each value in the array will be emitted one after another. Since your array only has one value, you will only get one emitted value.

You probably want to use [`of()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `from` operator emits the provided array in the form of each element as a stream of values.

(For simplicity, assume `someOtherFunc()` returns 'a' here)
Subscribing to `from(['a'])` would actually return 'a' as a value (and NOT ['a']).

I think what you're looking for is the `of` operator. This will emit the provided value (in your case - the array) as an array when subscribed.

In simpler terms (and in your context):

```
from(['a']).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
// outputs: 'a'

of(['a']).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
// outputs: ['a']
```

So the answer is: To meet your expected result, use the `of` operator instead of the `from` operator:

```
public dissasemble (file) {
    const signatureContainers = [someOtherFunc(file)];
    return of(signatureContainers);
}
```

Refer to these documentations for more details: [of](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of) and [from](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from) ( both are from different sources, just to share you more resources on RxJS :) )

Good luck!